# Python - have list and want to pull values from a table and put in new table

Tags: python, lookup-tables

Hello I am very new to python and apologize for asking something that may be silly. Any reference in the right direction is very much appreciated.

I have a list of strings (3500 gene names)

I have a table that contains 35000 genes along with several characteristics of those genes. 
Ie. Gene_ID Gene_Name chr_loc FPKM1 FPKM2 LFC ...etc

I want to find the genes in my list and pull out two values associated with those genes and place these three things for all 3500 genes in a new table.

I really appreciate any help!

Comment: I think you want to look up `dictionaries` in Python.

Comment: Post some code. What structures are you using? Lists, dictionaries? Is your data in a file? We need to see some detail

Comment: We need to know the format of your table, post an example.

Comment: So my file is an output file from cuffdiff. It is a tab delimited file. My list is a text file with each gene on a new line. Is that helpful or do I need to know more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the headers are in the file, here is the basic idea:

```
import csv
namelist = ['name1', 'name2']
fout = open('out.csv','w')
fout.write('header1,header2,header3')
fin = open('temp.csv','r')
reader = csv.DictReader(fin)
for row in reader:
  if row['header1'] in namelist:
      fout.write(newrow(row))
```

You will of course need to write a `newrow` function and adjust details for your input file format.